# Frequently update to GUI Failed on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have an issue that wp8.1 failed to frequently updating to GUI.
I have created a blank page, and two textblock to display numbers and a button to trigger(Receivingstart). The code will stop to update GUI after approximate 140 times on my computer. Is that correct behavior? Am I doing it wrong?
Thank alot!

```
private void ReceivingStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        TimerCallback callBack = new TimerCallback(add);
        Timer stateTimer = new Timer(callBack, null, 3000, 200);

    }

private async void add(object state)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            this.CountNumber.Text = count.ToString(); //GUI update
                            count++;
            var randomNumber = r.Next(0, 300);
            this.info.Text = randomNumber.ToString(); 
        });
    }
    private int count = 1;
```

Comment: you should use a dispatchertimer then you dont need to dispatch to the UI thread.

Comment: Hey @thumbmunkeys what if in a case that the textblock is binded and I need it to trigger this update when an async function is complete periodically?

Comment: The issue that's happening is that you have it as `async void`. The method is being passed on and called again before it is done.

Comment: @NateDiamond Hey, I am now add a heartRadioQueue.Enqueue(nummer) in the listener and running a dispatchTime to display on GUI(a binded ObserCollec.) and dequeue it and I took away the async and await. it still fails. The difficult thing is there are no exceptions throw out, which give me no clue, what is actually failing.